# Django how to render a custom template tag within a inclusion_tag for displaying it in the base.html

Tags: django, templates, calendar, django-templates

Hello I'm a Django Beginner.

I have a calendar that I want to be displayed on every site of my webpage, so I call this `{% include "tags/my_calendar.html" %}` in my base.html.

As I know so far, I can either display the calendar by creating a custom template tag or by using it in a standard Django view. I tested it with a standard Django view, by calling the calendar function through a urls.py, that works fine.
But I don't want the calendar being only displayed for a special url.

So can I do this by defining a custom template tag?

I tried this so far:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()
@register.inclusion_tag("tags/my_calendar.html")
def calendar():
"""
Show calendar of events for specified month and year
"""
  lToday = datetime.now()
  lYear = lToday.year
  lMonth = lToday.month
  my_workouts = ContestEvent.objects.filter(id__year=lYear, id__month=lMonth)
  lCalendar = WorkoutCalendar(my_workouts).formatmonth(lYear, lMonth)
  return {'calendar':  mark_safe(lCalendar)}
```

I override the HTMLCalender class as follows and all this works with Django standard view as mentioned before, but returning a render_to_response:

```
class WorkoutCalendar(HTMLCalendar):

    def __init__(self, workouts):
        super(WorkoutCalendar, self).__init__()
        # self.workouts = self.group_by_day(workouts)

    def formatday(self, day, weekday):
        if day != 0:
            cssclass = self.cssclasses[weekday]
            if date.today() == date(self.year, self.month, day):
                cssclass += ' today'
            return self.day_cell(cssclass, day)
        return self.day_cell('noday', '&nbsp;')

    def formatmonth(self, year, month):
        self.year, self.month = year, month
        return super(WorkoutCalendar, self).formatmonth(year, month)

    def day_cell(self, cssclass, body):
        return '<td class="%s">%s</td>' % (cssclass, body)
```

My \tags\my_calendar.html looks like this:

```
{% load calendar_tag %}
<div>
{% calendar %}
</div
```

What am I doing essentially wrong? I got the following error:

```
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/de/
Exception Type:     TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    

Caught an exception while rendering: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

---

**update1**
With the hint of [Daniel Roseman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104349/daniel-roseman) to make use of variable syntax `{{ calendar }}` instead of the tag syntax `{% calendar %}`  I got rid of the recursion error, but my calendar is still not displayed. I make a lot of investigations.

What is wrong here?

**update2**
after some investigation, I found this helpful short [description](http://iraniweb.com/blog/?p=9&cpage=1#comment-1791) on how to use custom template tag.
The mistake why the calender didn't show up, was that I was calling `{% include "tags/my_calendar.html" %}` in the base.html, instead of calling the function of my tag as `{% calendar <parameter> %}`. Whereas my tag template was ok, which calls the returned value of the tag function:

{{ calendar }}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your recursion error is because you are calling the `calendar` tag inside the template being rendered by that very same tag.

Your /tags/my_calendar.html file should actually look like this:

```
<div>
{{ calendar }}
</div>
```

Note the use of the variable syntax, to show you're rendering the value passed into the context, rather than the tag syntax. You don't need to use `load`, either.

Answer (score 0):

If the calendar is going to be displayed in each and every page of your site, then it makes more sense to create the calendar's controller in a context_processor.  This way, the fields are added to the Request object that is available to every template, and then just embed the calendar view in your base template.

James Bennet describes it clearly: http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/jun/14/django-tips-template-context-processors/

If you attach the call to the calendar as a closure or functor object, by the way, you can avoid the transaction costs on those pages where you don't render it.  This is what QuerySet does, and why it doesn't transact with the database until the data is actually requested.

Comment: @ Elf Sternberg: I will keep track of your reference. Thanks.

Comment: @ Daniel Roseman: when I use the variable syntax, I don't get a recursion error anymore, but my calendar is still not displayed. I cannot explain its behaviour. I will search for the problem.